# How can I use SUBSTITUTE to substitute an apostrophe?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to substitute spaces and apostrophes with hyphens.  I use this formula.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C129," ","-"),"'","-")
```

This has replaced the spaces but ignores the apostrophes.

I then tried

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C129," ","-"),"\'","-")
```

But that didn't help.  Is there a way to substitute apostrophes?

Comment: Your first formula works fine for me. I wonder if the data uses a different apostrophe character, e.g. not straight ' but curly ’ ?

Comment: Interesting thought.  I'll have to try that too

Comment: take one of your cells that contains your ' character and put it off to the side for some testing.  Lets assume that cell Q5.  Delete all the characters in front of the ' so that the ' is the left most character.  Then in another unused cell, use the following function:  `=CODE(Q5)`  Adjust the Q5 reference to match your test cell. ' on my system is character 39

Comment: @David if you put that as the answer I'll mark it as correct.  You could also include the idea of Forward Ed, but also I could just copy and paste the character to ensure it is the same character.

Comment: Heh heh thanks I'll gratefully take the points. Glad if I helped. Agreed the code function is excellent, very useful in many situations.

Comment: You've only ever asked one question, ask more, that's a quick way to get your points up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first formula works fine for me. I wonder if the data uses a different apostrophe character, e.g. not straight ' but curly ’ ?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one, will help you to replace Space & Apostrophe with Hyphen.**

[image]

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B121," ","-"),"'","-")," ","")
```

**Or you can use this also:**

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B121," ","-"),"'","-")
```

[image]

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: This is nearly identical to the question so the other answer is more correct (in the comments)

Comment: @Eoin,, yes both suggested formula are almost similar to the OP's formula that's what I've show him that he should find the error in his formula since the Syntax of the command is correct ☺ And that is the reason that I've added the part of active sheet as screen shot. ☺

Comment: In your first formula you deal with the space twice.  What is the purpose of this?

Comment: @Eoin,, I kept extra space as abandon precaution to mange extra space if any,, otherwise it works without it also,, and that's what the second formula is doing !

Comment: Which order do the substitutions take place?